# Libreoffice BASIC change slide title

Tags: libreoffice-basic

Attempting to adapt some old BASIC code, running into various snags.

Can't find the `Title` property for a slide, or a method to access it.

Any suggestions?

```
oDoc = StarDesktop.LoadComponentFromURL("private:factory/simpress", "_blank", 0, Array())       
oSlideList = oDoc.getDrawPages()
oSlide = oSlideList.insertNewByIndex(oSlideList.Count)

oTitle = oSlide.Title 'This is the missing property

oTitle.Text = "Recent History of Artificial Intelligence"
```

Version: 7.5.4.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 50(Build:2)
OS: Linux 5.4 (ubuntu 4:7.5.4 / 20.4.1); UI render: default; VCL: gtk3

Comment: Do you mean the shape which by default shows "Click to add Title?" I don't think there's anything special about that — it's simply a shape that happens to be set to `Title` style. For example, copying and pasting that shape produces a duplicate, so it's not unique to the slide. If you want to change it via macro, then like any shape, enumerate the shapes on the drawpage and choose the one you want. Or perhaps you mean the slide *name*, which starts at "Slide 1". This can be changed for example by going to Navigator and right-clicking "Rename".

Comment: Tks @JimK, but i need to do this using BASIC

Comment: Need to do what precisely? You didn't really respond to my comment, which asks which of the things I described are what you actually want.

Comment: my apologies, @JimK.  I am attempting to code Libreoffice BASIC to change the `Title` (or any other element) of a slide.  You solved my problem creating the slide, BTW (tks again for that!).

Comment: Still sounds like we're not communicating. Please say which of the following you want to ask about: a) properties of the Title style such as bold or font size, or b) the shape that by default shows "Click to add Title" and is set to Title style, for example, if you want to change what its text says or its position, or c) the slide name, the first of which is named Slide 1, or d) enumerating all shapes on a slide, not only those with Title style, in order to change their text or position or formatting or delete them, or e) properties of the slide such as transitions or backgrounds.